# Range of possible values for alpha, gamma and eta params of HLDA's Mallet implementation

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, topic-modeling, mallet

I'm trying to run the hlda algorytmm and producing a descriptive hierarchy of the input documents. The problem is I'm running diverse parameters configs and trying to understand how it works in an "empirical way", because I can not match the ones that are being used in the original papers (I understand it's a different team). E.g. alpha in Mallet seems to be eta in the paper, but I'm not very sure. Besides, I can not know the boundaries for each of them. I mean, the range of possible values for each parameter.

In the source code, there is some help:

```
double alpha; // smoothing on topic distributions
double gamma; // "imaginary" customers at the next
double eta;   // smoothing on word distributions.
```

First, I used the default values: alpha=10.0; gamma=1.0; eta = 0.1;

Then, I tryed running the algorythm by changing the values and interpret the results, but I can't understand the meaning of them. E.g. I think changing gamma (in Mallet) has an effect on the customers decition: to start a new node in the tree or to be placed in an existing one. So, if I set gamma = 0.5, less nodes should be produced, because 0.5 is half the probability of the default one, right? But the results with gamma=1 give me 87 nodes, and with gamma=0.5, it returns 98! And then, I'm asking me something new: is that a probability? I was trying to find the range of possible values in these two papers, but I didn't find them:

1. [Hierarchical Topic Models andthe Nested Chinese Restaurant Process](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2466-hierarchical-topic-models-and-the-nested-chinese-restaurant-process.pdf)
2. [The Nested Chinese Restaurant Process and BayesianNonparametric Inference of Topic Hierarchies](https://cocosci.berkeley.edu/tom/papers/ncrp.pdf)

I know I could be missing something, because I don't have the a good background on this, but that's why I'm asking here, maybe someone already had this problem and can help me understanding those limits.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be helpful to run multiple times with each hyperparameter setting. I suspect that gamma does not have a big influence on the final number of topics, and that what you are seeing could just be typical variability in the sampling process.

In my experience the parameter that has by far the strongest influence on the number of topics is actually eta, the topic-word smoothing.